# Mysql join from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables

```
friends
posts
members

friends
========
id, to, from (user_id's), status

there are 3 status's -1 = denied, 0 = no response/new, 1 = accepted



posts
=======
p_id, user_id (same as member_id), text


members
========
member_id, f_name, l_name
```

If like to select the text from the post in 'posts' combine it with the users name from 'members' and only display posts where the user_id is in the 'friends' table.

I would like to know if it can be done, I've tried an IN () statement in my query which worked, but it creates a new problem with generating the csv inside the IN (). I'd perfer to do this through mysql, but if it can't be done I may use a global variable to store friend data (but then it will not be upto date or will have to be refreshed when a user gets a new friend).

Comment: what does `to, from` means in `friends table?

Comment: when a new friend request is sent it records who sent it and who it was to and the status of the request -1 = denied, 0 = no response, 1 = accepted.

Comment: @arennaker The status part of `friends` is missing from the schema description above, could you add it?

Comment: @arennaker If A and B are friends, is there only one row with status 1, or is there one for each direction? (ie only `A B 1` or both `A B 1` and `B A 1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to find the name and posts of all *your* friends, not any friend that's in the friend table at all...?

Your own user id being in `$myId`, this should do it (newest posts first);

EDIT: Added status check for friends

```
SELECT m.f_name, m.l_name, p.`text`
FROM members m
JOIN posts p 
  ON m.member_id = p.user_id
JOIN friends f 
  ON f.`to` = m.member_id OR f.`from` = m.member_id
WHERE (f.`from` = $myId OR f.`to`= $myId)
  AND f.`status` = 1 AND m.member_id <> $myId
ORDER BY p.p_id DESC
```

Comment: this works, but it only selects if f.from = $myID not if f.to = $myID

Comment: this works great is it just does not include the members own post in the results, is there a way to change that?

Comment: @arennaker You mean include your own posts too? Just remove the `AND m.member_id <> $myId` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    SELECT p.text,m.f_name,m.l_name FROM posts p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN members m ON p.user_id=m.member_id
    where p.user_id in(select id from friends);

OR

   SELECT p.text,m.f_name,m.l_name FROM posts p 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN members m ON p.user_id=m.member_id
   INNER JOIN friends f on p.user_id=f.id
```

Comment: the issue is that it will only select data from the friends column 'to' or 'from' not both if either contains the $member_id

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a user_id and you want all the posts authored by "friends" of that user. This query starts at posts, joins that to friends (where the author is the "destination" of the friendship) (at which point the WHERE clause will filter out any non-friend posts), and then joins in members to fill out the author's name info.

```
SELECT 
  posts.p_id
  posts.text,
  CONCAT(members.f_name, " ", members.l_name)
FROM 
  posts
  JOIN friends ON posts.user_id = friends.to
  JOIN members ON posts.user_id = members.member_id
WHERE
  friends.from = ?
GROUP BY posts.p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a subquery to get all your friends since I assumed that if you have these records

```
Friends
==================================
ID      TO       FROM     STATUS
==================================
1       1        2         1
2       3        1         1
```

and your `member_id = 1`, your friends are 2, 3. right?

```
SELECT  b.f_name,
        b.L_name,
        c.`text`
FROM
    (
        SELECT `to` friendID
        FROM    friends
        WHERE   `status` = 1 AND
                `from` = ?             -- change this to your ID
        UNION
        SELECT `from` friendID
        FROM    friends
        WHERE   `status` = 1 AND
                `to` = ?               -- change this to your ID
    ) a  INNER JOIN members b
            ON a.friendID = b.member_ID
        LEFT JOIN   posts c
            ON a.friendID = c.user_id
```